# Need fetched id from query into url

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json

I am currently having a problem and i don't know how to fix.

Currently i have the script that fetch the latest id into

(ID Table)
but now i need instead of into

it in a meta redirect to another url.

**Just for example:**

```html
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="time; URL=https://api.omny.fm/orgs/[**Need id from Table here**]-a88800f49f6c/programs/a49c87f6-d567-4189-8692-a8e2009eaf86/clips/"
```

My current script and html i currently have:

**Javascript**

```html
$(document).ready(function() {

  // FETCHING DATA FROM JSON FILE
  $.getJSON("https://api.omny.fm/orgs/56ccbbb7-0ff7-4482-9d99-a88800f49f6c/programs/a49c87f6-d567-4189-8692-a8e2009eaf86/clips/",function(data) {
     
      $('#table').html(data.Clips[0].Id);
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```html
<html lang="en"><head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
</head>
  <p id="table"></p>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>

  <script src="./script.js"></script>



    </html>
```

I hope someone know how to get this done :D

Answer (score 0):

The tags say you are using JQuery. With it, you can get the value of the tag's `content` attribute with

```
const content = $('meta[http-equiv="refresh"]').attr('content')
```

(this will give you the value of a `content` attribute on the first matched tag)

Then you can parse out the ID, seems to be something like

```
const pattern = /api.omny.fm\/orgs\/([^-]+)-/ // get as group everything after "api.omny.fm/orgs/" until the next "-"
const id = c.match(pattern)[1]
```